# Need help in reading a file using SD card

Tags: arduino

I target is to read any file from the SD card when I type the file name on the serial monitor, using Arduino nano.

In the code below if I change the FileName with `random.txt`, it works, but I am trying to use the serial monitor to select the file I want.

String myInput;

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

const int cs = 4;
String FileName;
String line;
File file;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Initializing card...");
  pinMode(53, OUTPUT);
  if (!SD.begin(cs)) 
  {
    Serial.println("Card failed to initialize, or not present");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("Card Initialized.");
 }
void loop()
{
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Enter File Name.");  

  while (Serial.available()==0)  
  {                                      

  }  
   FileName=Serial.readString(); 
    Serial.println(FileName);

  file = SD.open(FileName);
    if (file) 
  {
    if(file.size()==0)
    {
      Serial.println("file " +FileName+ " is empty");
    }
    else{

    while (file.available())
    {
      Serial.write(file.read());
    }
    file.close();
     Serial.println("Task Complete");
    }
  }  

  else {
    Serial.println("Error, file " +FileName+ "does not exist");
  } 

}
```

No error messages. Code works, just stuck with this part-

```
Serial.println("Enter File Name."); 
while (Serial.available()==0)  
{                                      
}  
FileName=Serial.readString(); 
Serial.println(FileName);

file = SD.open(FileName);
```

SD card does not open the file I need.

Comment: what is your line end setting in Serial Monitor? try FileName.trim() after reading

Answer (score 0):

You have the usual newbie problem of using the input from Serial Monitor. Serial Monitor depending on the option selected in the drop-down list sends line ending characters. They are printed back if you print the value, but who would notice an additional empty line in output.

If the input is read into String, you can clear leading and trailing white space characters with `String.trim()` function.

`readString()` as used in your sketch, will wait a second after the last character received, because it doesn't know it was the last. You could use the fact that the line ending character is sent, to determine the end of the input. To read to String you can use `Serial.readStringUntil('\n);`. This will not read the terminator character, but you should still use trim() to cut away the '\r' (CR) character if it is sent.